# java.rmi.ServerException: RuntimeException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

When trying to access an ejb from a client , I get this exception :

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RuntimeException; nested exception is:   
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.handleException(LogInterceptor.java:421)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:209)
```

I can't figure for the life of me, what's wrong and where !

Answer (score 1):

I reckon that the EJB has an interceptor specified, hence every call the client makes goes via that interceptor. It looks like someone has set up some logging to be done for each call. So you need to go look at the LogInterceptor class - line 421 and figure out what problem it has. Probably it's not correctly initialised.

Then have severe words with the author - surely an Interceptor should be more robust than this. It should default to some sane behaviour and not obstruct the work, or at least should report a sensible error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing is to look at the JBoss source code for `LogInterceptor.java` for the particular version of JBoss that you're running (part of the magic of OSS).

Note that I found [this](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/jboss/ejb/plugins/LogInterceptor.java.html) but it appears to be out-of-date, or at least doesn't correspond to the source that you're running.